# socket.on function is not being called for the first time when react component mounted

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to create a simple real time chat app to practise with socket-io. I am using React to create UI and i am using NodeJS with Express web server. I have ChatPage React component to show messages.

I am emitting an event `newMessage` when a user joined to a room and i am sending a welcome message as data from server to client. At that time i am routing to ChatPage component and i am subscribing to `updateUserList` event in componentWillMount but this event is not coming up to that callback i defined. After some trials i realized a weird thing about this event. I subscribed this event from another .js file and i could see data that i sent from server.

```
// server.js
socket.on('joinRoom', (data, callback) => {
    const { username, roomName } = data
    if (username === '' || roomName === '') {
        if (callback) {
            return callback({ error: 'Username and password required!' })
        }
        return
    }

    socket.join(roomName, (err) => {
        if (err && callback) {
            return callback({ error: 'Could not connect to room.' })
        }

        socket.emit('newMessage', generateMessage('Admin', 'Welcome to chat app'))
        if (callback) {
            callback()
        }
    })
})


// ChatPage.js
componentWillMount() {
    const socket = io('http://localhost:3400')
    socket.on('newMessage', (message) => {
        console.log('newMessage', message)
    })
}



// event is coming to here instead!
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

export const getSocketIOClient = () => {
    const endpoint = "http://localhost:3400"
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint)
    socket.on('newMessage', (er) => {
        console.log('newMessage', message)
    })
    return socket;
}
```

Comment: try using `componentDidMount()`. I don't think `componentWillMount()` exists

Comment: @kkesley I have tried subscribe event in `componentDidMount()` and `constructor` but result did not change

Comment: can you make sure the `componentDidMount()` is called? e.g. put a `console.log` in the first line of `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: @kkesley All tried methods (constructor, comppnentWillMount, componentDidMount) is being called.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar porblem in my project. There I noticed few things which are missing in your code.

1. You need to call back join room in client code as well in `componentWillMount()` method.
2. You need to initialize `socket` in `state` variable. I don't know exactly why it doesn't work when we initialize in `const` variable but it works when we use `state` variable instead. I verified this code, it works fine even in the first time react component mount.

Here, is sample code:

```
import React from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class SocketExample extends React.Component {

    state = {
        chatMessage: '',
        chatMessages: [],
        socket: io.connect(`http://localhost:3001`),
    }

    submitChatMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.state.chatMessage.length > 0) {
            this.state.socket.emit('newMessage', {
                username: this.props.currentUser.username,
                message: this.state.chatMessage,
            });
            this.setState({
                chatMessage: '',
            })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.state.socket.on('connect', () => {
            this.state.socket.emit('join', { uniqueValue: chatRoomName });
        });
        this.state.socket.on("newMessage", data => {
            this.setState({
                chatMessages: [...this.state.chatMessages, data],
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.state.chatMessages.map(chat => {
                return <p>{chat.username + ': ' + chat.message}</p>
            })}</div>
        )    
    }  
}

export default SocketExample
```